# How can I add JMenuBars,JMenus and JMenuItems using IntelliJ's Swing GUI Designer?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, gui-designer

I can't find the components specified in the title anywhere in IntelliJ's Palette. I notice that the form has a JMenuBar, but I don't see it, and I don't know how to access it. Is there any way of using these components visually?

Comment: You don't "add" JMenuBars to a form in Swing; you call myFrame.setJMenuBar(theMenuBar). So that's probably why you can't drag-and-drop them. Unfortunately, that's all the help I can give you. Maybe you right-click on the form object or something, like you do in NetBeans.

Comment: In NetBeans you can drag & drop them. You can also drag them in Visual Swing 4 Eclipse, so, not being able to do the same thing in IntelliJ is odd.

Comment: Well, I think it used to be that you couldn't drag and drop them. At least that sticks in my head for some reason. Is there a tree of components like there is in NetBeans?

Comment: Yes, there is.In both IntelliJ and Visual Swing.

Comment: Can you right-click the JFrame in the tree and select to add a JMenuBar? That's the way I've done it in NetBeans before.

Comment: JFrame is not included in the palette. Right clicking the JFrame doesn't show a JMenuBar option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Creating menus like this isn't currently available in the IntelliJ designer. Their **official** solution is to use the JFormDesigner plugin for intelliJ. Or of course to code them by hand. Here is a link to the discussion in their forums :-

[IntelliJ thread](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/message/5222420)

Thanks,
jT

Comment: @Joao that link has become malicious. Just FYI.

Comment: I think I'm missing context re the above comment. The link redirects to intellij-support.jetbrains.com and is fine. Maybe it refers to some comments that were since deleted.